# DB2 Connect issue using Native OLE DB\MS OLEDB Provider for DB2

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, db2

I downloaded and installed the driver setup file, DB2OLEDB.exe, from here:

http://download.microsoft.com/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/progress?id=HYLbKUfGNl

Using the connection string that worked on another PC, I tried to create a Connection Object in an SSIS package. When I tested the connection I got this error:

```
Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. A TCPIP socket error has occurred (10057): A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.
```

Any suggestions on what the cause of this error is and how I might resolve this issue?

By the way, when I use the DB2 Configuration set up utility and test a connection from within that, I am able to successfully connect.

What other info can I provide to help you answer this question?

Thank you

Could this be related to a blocked port?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some research I've found two possible fixes.

The first link suggests calling BeginReceive after the EndAccept logic is complete.  Are you using script code, or just using the GUI without any scripting?

[TCP async sockets throwing 10057](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727074/tcp-async-sockets-throwing-10057)

---

---

The second link points to drivers / software on the PC.  It could be that you are missing a windows update or have faulty hardware / drivers.

I think this is less likely the case since you could connect to a different machine with the same connection string(?).  Can you verify this is a valid statement?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1bc3df95-c86d-4d25-aa20-30f61ed00c63/odd-socket-errors

---

---

If you could show the connection strings used for both the working and non working, and give a little more detail about The "Other PC" in comparison to the non-working PC... that would be helpful =]

---

---

If neither of the posts I've linked are the solution, this specific Google search has proven to yield some seemingly helpful results

"socket" "10057" "no address was supplied."

Answer (score 0):

If you follow all the steps illustrated here: http://www.bidn.com/blogs/PatrickLeBlanc/ssis/700/connecting-to-db2-using-ssis do you still get the same result?

Maybe a silly question, did you restart the computer after the installation?
Are you an admin user on one machine and not on the other?

You could try to verify the port connectivity with a quick telnet command:

> `telnet your-db-host your-db-listening-port`

If it connects, that one is off the list.