# C# TCP Socket Error 10057 with async-recv method

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, runtime-error, socketexception

Before I start, yes I have viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727074/tcp-async-sockets-throwing-10057) page.

I have made the code I'm using available as [HSHK](http://pastebin.com/74JeG1TU), and [CRYSRelatedSocketTrio](http://pastebin.com/BVtCrLZ6) on pastebin

The specific problem I'm having with C# Sockets is with a async receive method I'm using. You can see where the error is thrown at line 13-20 in the HSHK file.

Here is the breakdown for the CRYSRelatedSocketTrio class

**-TCP_A_HSHK - accepting socket**

**-TCP_HSHK_RS1 - receiving socket**

**-TCP_HSHK_RS2 - sending socket (not important)**

The TCP_A_HSHK socket is started at the beginning of the CRYSRelatedSocketTrio file. Next, the sending socket is configured and bound (code not shown). Then, the accepting socket begins listening and accepting.

**Note: CRYSTrio in the HSHK file is a local CRYSRelatedSocketTrio variable**

Does anyone know why Socket ErrorCode 10057 is being thrown at line 13-20 in the HSHK file?